# Text Classification : LSTM vs Feedforward

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm, text-classification

I am training a text classification model.

**Task** : Given a description, identify the quantifier

**For ex** 
1) This field contains the total revenue amount in USD -> amount

2) This has city code -> code

3) total deposit amount is 34 -> amount

4) contains first name info -> name

5) contains last nme -> name

For the given task, it makes sense to model this as a text classification problem.

I took two approaches

Approach 1 :

a) Use glove embedding to get vector represenation

b) Use feedforward NN to classify data into 1 of 11 possible output classes

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, 
                               weights=[embedding_matrix], 
                               input_length=maxlen, 
                               trainable=False))
    model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
```

This approach gives me 80% test accuracy

Approach 2 : I plan to use LSTM because they can also learn the context and from previous words

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, 
                               weights=[embedding_matrix], 
                               input_length=maxlen, 


    model.add(layers.LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

    epochs = 100
    batch_size = 32

    model.summary()
```

The problem is irrespective of what i do LSTM never gets above 40% accuracy mark. It gets stuck on it from start to end.

Morevoer, the feedforward net ( Approach 1 ) can detect simple cases like "total amount is 6 usd" but LSTM is unable to get even this correct and predicts it as Other

My question is why does LSTM ( with added power of context ) fails to improve upon feedforward. What should i do to improve it .

Comment: Why do you use different metrics?

Comment: The metrics eventually are the same under the hood

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly why, but my guess is sample size/data quality. The deeper learning, the more data it needs and the more sensitive it is to small biases in the training data. If you have a small dataset, it might be possible that a less complex model will serve better. [image]

Another possibility is that LSTMs are very strong at context and position based reasoning, and from what I glean about your task it seems that you are looking more for keywords and less for long distance relations. This may also explain why feedforward works better

Comment: Thanks doe your response ! 
The code indicates the balance amount = here it is code
The balance amount against the code = here it is amount
Hence power of lstm to understand context is needed